# on_typing not responding to typing discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am attempting to have a bot recognise when a user is typing and if that user is me, it sends a message. I don't know if I'm using this wrong but I read the API and at still doesn't make sense to me. the bot is not responding to any typing that I do in the default chat of my discord test server. I tried simplifying it to make sure that it actually wasn't seeing my typing and it still doesn't work, any ideas. the code is below.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

token = ('~my token~')
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

client.case_insensitive = (True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(user):
    print(f'~Temp~ {user} joined the server.')

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(server):
    print(f'~Temp~ {server} joined')

@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    print('Ready')
    '''
    if user.id == id1:
        await channel.send('1')
    elif user.id == id2:
        await channel.send('2')
    else:
        await channel.send('3')
    '''

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('~Temp~ Message found')

client.run(token)
```

Comment: You may need to set [`Intents.typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.typing) to `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable intents in order to work

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(.., intents=intents)
```

[A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)